# How to convert c# object into json object and send response to ajax method in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic

I have using jquery ajax method as below and call one asp method in it.In which I want to convert C# object into JSON object and return it to the response on success of ajax method...
but I am unable to convert c# object into json ....

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: loc + "/" + methodName,
            data: "{" + args + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSuccess,
           fail: onFail
        });
```

Comment: Just to make things clear: are you using ASP.NET or classic ASP because those are 2 completely different things and your tags are not consistent between them?

Comment: Have a look at json.net by James Newton King http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: No I didn't look for json.net,I think it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

look at JSON.NET

this is a simple sample that shows how to convert JSON to C# object and vice versa.

[click here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingJSON.html)